# XAMPP already installed on the MacBook, MySQL and phpMyAdmin not starting

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

When using `//Localhost/phpMyAdmin`, I get:

> Forbidden
> You don't have permission to access this resource.

This seenms to be a common error. None of the solutions I found resolved this problem. I discovered XAMPP is already installed on my Macbook which I find very puzzling as I have never installed this. If I use XAMPP to start phpMyAdmin or MySQL, the services won't start up.